# Java equivalent of instance initializer called after constructor

Tags: java

I've been reading about instance initializers in Java, and it's been explained that code common to all constructors can be put into them because they are called every time a new instance of a class is created.  Is there an equivalent of instance initializers that run after constructors, for code that would be common to all constructors, but depends on what happens in the constructors?

Comment: *Is there an equivalent of instance initializers that run after constructors* No.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is perhaps a bit severe?  There is nothing in Java, but there are conventions, and more recently the `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` annotation is to assist with that.

Comment: @Taylor What is the `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` annotation?

Comment: @Taylor Sure, but the question was, is there an equivalent to instance initializers. If you're willing to use AOJ (and follow the conventions), then you have something that looks similar to an instance initializer.

Comment: It's an annotation that many CDI's and IOC frameworks (e.g. Spring) will pick up on and invoke after instance creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't an exact equivalent. If you want to run some common code, you can always factor out a method and call it at the end of all your constructors:

```
public class C {
    private int x = 5;
    private String y;

    public C(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        endConstructor();
    }

    public C(String x) {
        this.x = x.length;
        endConstructor();
    }

    private void endConstructor() {
        y = x + "!";
    }
}
```

---

Sometimes, what seems like a situation where you want to call the same code at the "end" of all constructors can be refactored so that this code is in a single main constructor. Then, all other constructors call it using `this()`. For the example above:

```
public class C {
    private int x = 5;
    private String y;

    public C(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        y = x + "!";
    }

    public C(String x) {
        this(x.length);
    }
}
```

The main constructor can be private, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation can be used.

If your class has its dependencies injected using setter methods, then its  constructor won't fully initialize an instance. Thus, additional "initializations" need to be performed after all the setter methods have been called.

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner at programming, I'm not sure what you mean by "dependencies injected using setter methods."  What excatcly does `@PostConstruct` do?  Can I just put it above a method and it will be called after constructors?

Comment: @mCoder It requires a framework to process the `@PostConstruct`. You don't have such a framework in plain Java. It's something extra used on bigger projects.

Comment: Specifically you can look at a IoC (Inversion of Control) or DI (Dependency Injection) container like Spring Framework or Google Guice. As Andreas stated, the annotation is meaningless in a basic JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If you think something happens in constructor:

```
class X {
private int x;
public X() {
// Code that sets x
// =-=-= HERE =-=-=
}
}
```

Insert the code you want to happen after the constructor... At the end of constructor.

If you have many constructors and don't want to duplicate code:

```
class X {
private int x;
public X() {
// Code that sets x
init();
}
public X(int x2) {
x = x2;
init();
}
private void init() {
// =-=-= HERE =-=-=
}
}
```

If every constructor invokes `init`, we may say this is invoked as a part of constructor, not after it. Imagine a train with one additional car following it, 50cm from it. Both have the same destination/time. Why couldn't we connect the train with standalone car?